# Difference between dynamic completion and hippie expand

Tags: completion, dabbrev, hippie-expand

I've been starting to use dynamic completion with icicle-support in Emacs (command `icicle-complete` with `dynamic-completion-mode` on), but now I've stumbled over `hippie-expand` and it sounds like they both are doing very similar things, so I'm not sure which one to use. What is even the difference between the two?

Comment: I know what `hippie-expand` is, but what do you *specifically* mean by "dynamic completion"?

Comment: @phils Ah, sorry, I should have been more precise. I'm using the command `icicle-complete` with `dynamic-completion-mode` on.

Comment: @Drew That's weird, I think it should be quite old. I have the instructions from here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_in_Other_Buffers#h5o-3 but I'm pretty sure it doesn't depend on `icicles`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question well about comparing the two. But the doc of each should help. `completion.el` is very *old*, and the only doc for it is in that source file.

`completion.el` works with the text you type. It can learn from what you type, if you tell it to. It can save what it's "learned" persistently, if you want it to. In other respects it's similar to dabbrev.

`hippie-expand`, as I understand it, knows various predefined ways of computing different kinds of things. You can have it use dabbrev as one of the ways, for example.

Hopefully someone else will provide a better description of `hippie-expand` and perhaps compare the two better. I don't expect that there's really any overlap between the two, but I could be wrong. You can no doubt use both, binding them to different keys.

My guess is that the best approach is to just experiment with each. To start with what `completion.el` offers (with or without [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)), read the Commentary in the source file.